# Encode/Decode a String to BigInteger in Java

Tags: java, hash, hex, ascii

I'm working on a implementation where I should convert a long hash `String` to a `BigInteger` back and forth (the function should be reversible) but I'm not figuring out how to make it work in Java with those classes.

My first idea was to do something as follows:

```
given s:String
for every character in the input string:
    convert char to decimal ASCII representation (i.e. 'a' -> '97')
    append result to s
build a BigDecimal with the resulting s
```

but the problem is (as commented by many users) the length for the conversion, because ASCII characters goes from 0 to 255. It could be changed from `'a' -> '97'` to `'a' -> '097'`, but again there's a problem in decoding, removing heading zeroes to every character (BTW, doing the algorithm less efficient)

So, in conclusion, the algorithm proposed here is not the best idea so I'm open to some other solutions. Also, if there is any library or built-in method in `String` and/or `BigInteger`, it's helpful too. The signature is

```
public class EncodeUtil {
    public BigInteger encode(String s) {...}
    public String decode(BigInteger bi) {...}
}
```

and the condition is that `decode(encode("som3_We1rd/5+ring"))` outputs `"som3_We1rd/5+ring"`

I think it's worth to say that received strings for decoding are hashes like `lQ5jkXWRkrbPlPlsRDUPcY6bwOD8Sm/tvJAVhYlLS3WwE5rGXv/rFRzyhn4XpUovwkLj2C3zS1JPTQ1FLPtxNXc2QLxfRcH1ZRi0RKJu1lK8TUCb6wm3cDw3VRXd21WRsnYKg6q9ytR+iFQykz6MWVs5UGM5NPsCw5KUBq/g3Bg=`

Any idea/suggestion is welcomed. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You should use StringBuilder when you have to append so many times.

Comment: @ghoul932 That's for sure, I'm just writing the algorithm as abstract as possible, even when we know we are using Java

Comment: This is going to fail for hash("abz") -> 9798122. How do you know where to delimit/split the integer? You can't use two digits ('z' -> 122).

Comment: 'Reversible hash' is a contradiction in terms. What you're doing here is encoding and decoding.

Comment: The algorithm mentioned in q. will only work if some characters(like ASCII values 1, 10, 11, 12) are strictly not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does approximately what you want - but what you have asked, specifically, will not work when the number of digits per "decimal ASCII representation" is variable. Also, what you want is not a [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function):

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Reversible Hash a String to BigInteger in Java";

        System.out.println(HashUtil.notReallyHash(s));
        System.out.println(HashUtil.notReallyUnhash(HashUtil.notReallyHash(s)));
    }
}

class HashUtil {
    private static final byte SENTINEL = (byte) 1;

    public static BigInteger notReallyHash(String s) {
        CharBuffer charBuf = CharBuffer.wrap(s.toCharArray());
        ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(charBuf.length() * Character.BYTES + 1);

        byteBuf.put(SENTINEL); // need this in case first byte is 0 - biginteger will drop it
        byteBuf.asCharBuffer()
               .append(charBuf);

        return new BigInteger(1, byteBuf.array());
    }

    public static String notReallyUnhash(BigInteger bi) {
        ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bi.toByteArray());

        byteBuf.get(); // SENTINEL

        CharBuffer charBuf = byteBuf.asCharBuffer();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int count = charBuf.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            sb.append(charBuf.get());
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Yields:

```
361926078700757358567593716803587125664654843989863967556908753816306719264539871333731967310574715835858778584708939316915516582061621172700488541380894773554695375367299711405739159440282736685351257712598020862887985249
Reversible Hash a String to BigInteger in Java
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your answers. Besides, I made some changes in my question based on your observations

Comment: Wow! it does the job perfectly. May I ask: did you know the method from before or you figured out? how do you arrived to this solution?

Comment: Check out base64 - in Java 8 there is java.util.Base64. I knew you could call `BigInteger.toByteArray()` to get an array so it followed there was a mechanism to get one back. I chose this constructor because I didn't want to even try messing around with dealing with negative values, but you can try the other ctor that takes a byte array and see if that works. Finally, base64 or any other encoding scheme should be used. This is not a sensible solution but it does illustrate a use of ByteBuffers and CharBuffers!